# Grunt JS Task Runner - Tasks directory not found, Task "vs-grunt-task-reader" not found - File path prefixed with /c$/

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, gruntjs, task-runner-explorer

I've just started at a new company and we pulled all the code from source to my local computer. Everything runs fine, except the Task Runner Explorer is failing to run Gruntfile.js because it can't find vs-grunt-task-reader.js

Here's the error:

```
Failed to run "C:\Projects\DQ2 Application\deltaquestv2_frontend\DeltaQuest2\DeltaQuest2\DQ2-Client\Gruntfile.js"...
```

Then:

```
Tasks directory "\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\TaskRunnerExplorer\Scripts" not found.
Warning: Task "vs-grunt-task-reader" not found.
```

And the command that fails:

```
cmd.exe /c grunt -b "C:\Projects\DQ2 Application\deltaquestv2_frontend\DeltaQuest2\DeltaQuest2\DQ2-Client" --gruntfile "C:\Projects\DQ2 Application\deltaquestv2_frontend\DeltaQuest2\DeltaQuest2\DQ2-Client\Gruntfile.js" --tasks "\c$\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\TaskRunnerExplorer\Scripts" vs-grunt-task-reader
```

When I run the command in cmd, I get the same message, but when I change the `\c$`to `C:`, it works runs successfully.

Is there a way to change the `\c$` to `C:` within Visual Studio or the Grunt config?

Or is there any reason why the Grunt Task Runner runs fine on one computer and not mine?

Not sure if this makes any difference to this question, but if I run "\myComputerName\c$" it opens C: in explorer

Answer (score 0):

I found a tutorial on setting up Grunt in Visual Studio 2015, and the first thing it says to do is: "Install Web Essential 2015 from Tools / Extensions and Updates".

Problem solved!

https://dvoituron.com/2015/07/15/grunt-and-bower-in-visual-studio-2015/